# Magento: Export customers from version 1.5 and import them in version 1.8.1

Tags: magento, import

I have developed a new shop in Magento version 1.8.1 and my previous shop was in version 1.5.1. Now I want to import the customers from the old shop into the new shop.

I have used "**Data Flow Profiles**" for this but it is not importing it to the new system. It is giving me the error of "**Website not defined**". I have tried different things in the csv but nothing worked for me. Is this the version problem with both the system?

So how can I do that?

Comment: Questions about Magento should be asked on [magento.se]

Comment: I have asked it on the link you given. Can you give me the solution there. The ink is http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22118/magento-export-customers-from-version-1-5-and-import-them-in-version-1-8-1